# How to put symbols under letter in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'm having trouble to write some phonetic symbol like this [image], where the symbol underneath is '>'

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods to combine multiple signs, but there are 1000's of symbols to choose from.

You can use add icons, signs and symbols as unicode characters: Here is a good overview: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block

As example for instance with currency symbols: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+20A0

Here you can see the Euro sign "U+20AC" what you can add in your markdown as `&#x20AC;` what gives €, so write `&#x` then the hexidecimal number and finish with `;`

Ik hope this helps  (`&#x1F60A;`)